# Sending and receiving [][] byte through a Websocket in Golang

Tags: arrays, go, websocket

I have a two-dimensional byte array:

```
data := [][]byte{{104, 105}, {104, 105}}
```

which I need to transport through a websocket connection, but I don't find a way how to convert this array so I can efficiently reconvert it back to a two-dimensional array on my java client.

```
func socketManager (connection *websocket.Conn ){

    fmt.Print("Websocket connection established ")

    //determining the request
    for {

    //awaiting messages from clients
    messageType, message, err := connection.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        //ending connection when error accursed
        Logger.LogError(err.(error).Error())
        break
    }

        data := [][]byte{{104, 105}, {104, 105}}

        //How can I send this two dimensional byte array?
        err = connection.WriteMessage(websocket.BinaryMessage, message)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write:", err)
            break
        }




    err = connection.WriteMessage(messageType, message)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("write:", err)
        break
    }

    }

    //closing the connection
    defer connection.Close()
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide more details for an accurate answer. At first glance, you'll need to decide how to serialize it. Either use an existing encoding (json, protobuf, etc...) or a custom solution.

Comment: What encoding do you want to use?

Comment: Hello! I have added a code snipped and edited my question.

Comment: Any encoding would be fine.

Comment: @JulieNoobie, What is your java client expecting? Maybe just marshal the data as json?

Comment: In a real case scenario, those would be pictures. I didn't want to use json with base64, because of the data increase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-dimensional arrays are usually defined in terms of both their dimensions (i.e. "width" and "height") and their contents (the entire list of individual items which should be broken up into constituent "rows" or "columns"). However, if the constituent arrays might have different lengths then you may need another approach entirely.

Your task is to decide how you want to serialize this data so that your client can deserialize it and to emphasize any critical aspects of this transmission (e.g. data size, performance, ease of interoperability, etc).

Here are some possible solutions:

1. Matrix dimensions and contents. If your data will always have a consistent "width" and "height" then you could use a raw encoding to serialize two `uint16`s (or other appropriate size) representing those values and then a sequence of the raw bytes. To deserialize, the client would just need to read two integers to know the dimensions of the matrix and could then populate the rest of the data accordingly. An example message might look like this (as hexadecimal bytes):

   `0002 0002 6869 6869`
2. Length and contents. If each sub-array could have a different length then you could simply raw encode a sequence of tuples of "length" (e.g. as `uint32`) and raw byte contents, e.g. (as hexadecimal bytes):

   `0000 0002 6869 0000 0002 6869`
3. JSON and Base64. If interoperability and ease of integration are more important (and large data sizes are not a major concern) then you could simply serialize your data as a JSON array of strings, each of which is a Base64 encoded byte array. This way, the client need only deserialize the JSON array and Base64 decode each element. This solution also easily allows for varying size sub-arrays. An example message might look like this (as a JSON string):

   `["aGk=","aGk="]`

Ultimately, go has [many builtin `encoding` packages](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/) that you can use to serialize this data. There is no single "right" answer, so your implementation choice should be driven by your business needs.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking time to help me. - I didn't want to use the JSON with the base64 approach, because of the data increase, but I guess I'll have to take this path.

Comment: Happy to help! You could also use a hybrid "length/contents" approach whereby the data is serialized as a sequence of `length uint32` and then raw bytes, so the client just reads the "length" int, then that many bytes, and repeats until all data is consumed, with each iteration resulting in a sub-array